# Eclipse - Can't set preferences

Tags: linux, eclipse, kde-plasma

I've installed eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), and than i've installed spring plugin as i always do with a new linux installation (by the way i am running Manjaro Linux 15.09 fully updated with KDE) but this time i am facing a problem i have never seen before!
Everytime i go to the preferences window, the right pane won't update according to the selected option.
**Ex:** when i open the preferences window, if i try to drill down the "General" option, the right pane won't update, no matter what i choose in the left pane!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Same Problem here with Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2), Open JDK 8 and Ubuntu 16.04. Any proper solution appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The reason was because Eclipse didn't set up completely - there was some background tasks running (**freezing** actually).

Try to run Eclipse with another JRE version. I have this problem with 8u60, but everything is fine (as fine as it can be with Eclipse) when I use 8u45.

Off topic - I strongly recommend everyone to stop using Eclipse and go to Intellij IDEA. Your life will become much more happy.

**UPD** I faced that problem again with the new workspace, so maybe this isn't about JRE version. Try to wait a few minutes, reopen workspace again, this worked out for me.

Comment: I've tried everything... i ended up installing the previous version of eclipse (Luna) and it worked just fine... i suppose it is some kind of bug with this new eclipse version (a friend of mine had the same problem in a Ubuntu machine... same solution)

Comment: Sorry to hear you didn't solve it. Personally, as I said before, I recommend you to use Intellij IDEA instead of Eclipse - it's much better, have free Java SE version and the price of full version is not very high. As one man said: Eclipse is only free if your time and sanity are worth nothing. Or if you need Java EE in your work and can't buy full version of IDEA - NetBeans is better than Eclipse too, IMHO :) I can't understand how could it happen that Eclipse became so popular